Getting ETF from specific exchange via data type stocks into an Excel-Sheet
I want to get the ETF with ISIN: IE00BZ56RD98 from the exchange in Berlin automatically into my Excel-Sheet. 
Therefore, I declared Cell A1 to data type stocks. 
I was able to find the ETF in the search menu from data type stocks and entered it like this:
A1 = WisdomTree:US Qual DG (XNAS:DGRW)

As you can see this is not referring to the exchange in Berlin. 
Therefore, I wanted to change it and typed the following into the cell:
A1 = WisdomTree:US Qual DG (XBER:WTDT)

Unfortunately, when I type this into Excel it automatically changes it to:
A1= WisdomTree:AI and Innov (BATS:WTAI)


When I look on the website of the exchange in Berlin the data I entered seems to be correct:


Do you have any idea how to get the ETF from the exchange in Berlin automatically into the Excel-Sheet?

Possibly the data provider doesn't cover that holding at that exchange. The supported market identifier codes for Germany are Deutsch Boerse XFRA and Xetra XETR But those don't work either with WTDT
